# Add images to ImageList at runtime in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, listview, imagelist

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and coding in VB.

I am getting the directories in a folder to populate a ListView and have no issues doing that. 
I can also add images to an ImageList by searching through the folder for the files. 
The thing I cannot do is connect the two.  If I hard code my items in and hard code my images in, they work just fine.

I also need to figure out how to add a Tag for each item.  The tag should be the name of the directory.  (dir from the first For Each)

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Set ListView view mode to show Large Icons
    ListView1.View = View.LargeIcon

    Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(filePath & "Resources\IETMS\")
    Dim dir As String

    For Each dir In dirs
        dir = dir.Replace(dir.Substring(0, dir.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), "")
        ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(dir))
    Next

    'Create ImageList objects. 
    Dim imageListLarge As New ImageList()
    imageListLarge.ImageSize = New Size(100, 100)

    Dim filesList As String() = Directory.GetFiles(filePath & "Resources\IETMS\")
    Dim files As String
    For Each files In filesList
        'files = files.Replace(files.Substring(0, files.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), "")
        imageListLarge.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile(files))
    Next

    'Assign the ImageList objects to the ListView.
    ListView1.LargeImageList = imageListLarge

End Sub
```

Here is the same code but hard coding the info. 
This next example works exactly how I want it to. 
Only problem is Some clients might have all 6 items and some might not. 
Thats the reason for needing the For Each.

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Set ListView view mode to show Large Icons
        ListView1.View = View.LargeIcon

        ' Create items for the listview
        Dim item1 As New ListViewItem("Item 1", 5)
        Dim item2 As New ListViewItem("Item 2", 4)
        Dim item3 As New ListViewItem("Item 3", 0)
        Dim item4 As New ListViewItem("Item 4", 3)
        Dim item5 As New ListViewItem("Item 5", 1)
        Dim item6 As New ListViewItem("Item 6", 2)

        'Set the group for the items
        item1.Group = ListView1.Groups("IETMs")
        item2.Group = ListView1.Groups("IETMs")
        item3.Group = ListView1.Groups("IETMs")
        item4.Group = ListView1.Groups("IETMs")
        item5.Group = ListView1.Groups("IETMs")
        item6.Group = ListView1.Groups("IETMs")

        'Set a tag for the items
        item1.Tag = "This is file 1"
        item2.Tag = "This is file 2"
        item3.Tag = "This is file 3"
        item4.Tag = "This is file 4"
        item5.Tag = "This is file 5"
        item6.Tag = "This is file 6"

        'Add the items to the ListView.
        ListView1.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6})

        'Create ImageList objects. 
        Dim imageListLarge As New ImageList()
        imageListLarge.ImageSize = New Size(100, 100)

        ' Initialize the ImageList objects with bitmaps
        Dim image1 = Bitmap.FromFile(filePath & "Resources\IETMS\file1.ico")
        Dim image2 = Bitmap.FromFile(filePath & "Resources\IETMS\file2.ico")
        Dim image3 = Bitmap.FromFile(filePath & "Resources\IETMS\file3.ico")
        Dim image4 = Bitmap.FromFile(filePath & "Resources\IETMS\file4.ico")
        Dim image5 = Bitmap.FromFile(filePath & "Resources\IETMS\file5.ico")
        Dim image6 = Bitmap.FromFile(filePath & "Resources\IETMS\file6.ico")

        imageListLarge.Images.AddRange({image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6})

        'Assign the ImageList objects to the ListView.
        ListView1.LargeImageList = imageListLarge

    End Sub
```

---

### Here is my modified code.

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Set ListView view mode to show Large Icons
        ListView1.View = View.LargeIcon

        Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(filePath & "Resources\IETMS\")
        Dim dir As String

        For Each dir In dirs
            dir = dir.Replace(dir.Substring(0, dir.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), "")
            ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(dir, dir))
        Next

        'Create ImageList objects. 
        Dim imageListLarge As New ImageList()
        imageListLarge.ImageSize = New Size(100, 100)

        Dim filesList As String() = Directory.GetFiles(filePath & "Resources\IETMS\")
        Dim files As String
        Dim files2 As String

        For Each files In filesList
            files2 = files.Replace(files.Substring(0, files.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), "")
            files2 = files2.Replace(".ico", "")
            imageListLarge.Images.Add(files2, Bitmap.FromFile(files))
        Next

        'Assign the ImageList objects to the ListView.
        ListView1.LargeImageList = imageListLarge

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ImageList collection items also can take a key for easy look-up:

```
imageListLarge.Images.Add(files, Bitmap.FromFile(files)))
```

Then you can reference them by the key:

```
Dim bmp As Bitmap = imageListLarge.Images("my file name")
```

---

When you add your ListView item, you can use the ImageKey as the reference:

```
Dim item1 As New ListViewItem("2J-F108-100", "2J-F108-100")
```

this assumes you added the image with the same key:

```
imageListLarge.Images.Add("2J-F108-100", Bitmap.FromFile(...)))
```

---

Also, make sure to add your images before adding the ListItems:

```
Dim imageListLarge As New ImageList()
imageListLarge.ImageSize = New Size(100, 100)
Dim filesList As String() = Directory.GetFiles(filePath & "Resources\IETMS\")
Dim files2 As String
For Each files As String In filesList
  files2 = files.Replace(files.Substring(0, files.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), "")
  files2 = files2.Replace(".ico", "")
  imageListLarge.Images.Add(files2, Bitmap.FromFile(files))
Next
ListView1.LargeImageList = imageListLarge

ListView1.View = View.LargeIcon
Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(filePath & "Resources\IETMS\")
For Each dir As String In dirs
  dir = dir.Replace(dir.Substring(0, dir.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), "")
  ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(dir, dir))
Next
```

Comment: Not really sure how this helps me.  If you could explain what this can do for my situation, I would appreciate it.  And I do thank you for your input.

Comment: @xRuhRohx Updated the post.  You don't want to use the index value for linking the images, you want to use a key.  Whether you use a filename or your own key is up to you.

Comment: Ok I think I understand.  I have the ListView populated and the imageList populated. But the images are still not showing for me. Anyway to see if they are matching while it is running?  Like loop through both lists and see if they are matching?

Comment: I looped through the ListView and it showed all the Items and the ImageList shows 6 items which is the correct number of items, but my images just aren't showing.

Comment: @xRuhRohx Well, I can't see what you did.  What "key" are you using for your images and what key are you using for the ImageKey property of the ListViewItem?

Comment: @xRuhRohx Your "dir" and "files2" variables look like different strings, but you are expecting them to match.  I don't think they do.  The key must be the same.  In one version, you are replacing the "ico" and not in the other.

Comment: Well in the IETMS folder, There are 6 folders and 6 .ico files.  The folder names (dir) match the files2 without the .ico on the end.  So one folder might be named EngineOne and the .ico file would be EngineOne.ico.  I removed .ico in the variable files2 so it would hold EngineOne and match the dir which would be EngineOne

Comment: @xRuhRohx Updated post.  Add the images to the ImageList control *before* adding the ListItem objects that reference those images.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same but it's not working my images are not displaying however I did some debug and they are being read correctly ... don't know what is going on. Using VS 2013 and VB

Comment: @ocespedes I clearly can't see your code from here.  If you are still having problems, please post a new question, and make sure to document it properly with code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @LarsTech thanks for repliying, but I've managed to do it. I didn't have it clear that I needed to add a ListViewItem per image. That was my issue